# How do I freeze the requirements of a tox test environment?

Tags: python, pip, subprocess, requirements.txt, tox

I usually install my requirements from an abstract file like so:

```
# requirements.in
pytest
```

I define test environments in a `tox.ini` like so:

```ini
[testenv]
deps = -rrequirements.in
commands = pytest
```

How do I freeze the installed versions of the dependencies to a `requirements.txt` file?

I tried using this bash one-liner:

```ini
commands_post = python -m pip freeze --all > requirements.d/pytest.txt
```

However, this prints the requirements to the standard output instead of redirecting them to the file:

```bash
pytest-py312: commands_post[0]> python -m pip freeze --all '>' requirements.d/pytest.txt
```

Note that the `>` is getting escaped instead of being interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this is to allow using bash and run the `pip freeze` command inside bash:

```
[testenv]
allowlist_externals = bash,/bin/bash,/usr/bin/bash
commands = pytest
commands_post = bash -c "python -m pip freeze --all > requirements.d/pytest.txt"
deps = -rrequirements.in
```

> **Note**: This solution is not portable to systems without bash.

Answer (score 1):

You should use pip-tools to freeze your requirements.

https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools

A suitable tox env could look like this
https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded/blob/0b050952856ed28b1d5f534c951c07bf7dabbeff/tox.ini#L72

Comment: I don't want to make pip-tools a requirement of my package. Keeping my run- and test time requirements separate is why I am using requirements.in files in the first place.

Comment: Also, I am aiming for reproducibility, so would prefer using only pip's dependency resolver. Instead of adding pip-tools' one.

Comment: @bengt you do not need to make pip-tools a dependency of your package - just use the deps directive of tox to install it. And of course is pip-tools able to even create hashes of packages, so it is way better than pip for reproducabilty, as the latter only freezes versions - which can be overwritten on PyPI.

Comment: How would one reproduce an environment when the package was deleted from PyPI?

Comment: If you want real reproducibility, you need to run your own package system. But when it is removed, and your installation fails, you at least know it has changed, eg from a malicious attack

Comment: I think at some point you have to trust something and someone. I for one am willing to trust the developers of my dependencies to keep published versions available, if at all possible. Also, I trust PyPI to operate the package index at least as secure as a self hosted one. In effect I consider relying on the public packaging infrastructure okay for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

One could use Python's [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function:

```ini
[testenv]
deps = -rrequirements.in
commands = pytest
commands_post = python -c "import subprocess; open('requirements.d/pytest.txt', 'wb').write(subprocess.check_output(['python', '-m', 'pip', 'freeze', '--all', '--exclude-editable']))"
```

> **NOTE**: This copies the requirements from C to Python memory and back to C for writing them to disk. This is cumbersome and slow.

Answer (score 0):

One could use pip's internal API:

```ini
[testenv]
deps = -rrequirements.in
commands = pytest
commands_post = python -c "from pip._internal.operations.freeze import freeze; open('requirements.d/pytest.txt', 'w').write('\n'.join(freeze(exclude_editable=True, skip=())));"
```

> **Note**: [Using pip's internal API is discouraged.](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program) So proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

One could use Python's [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) function:

```ini
[testenv]
deps = -rrequirements.in
commands = pytest
commands_post = python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.run(['python', '-m', 'pip', 'freeze', '--all', '--exclude-editable'], stdout=open('requirements.d/pytest.txt', 'w'), text=True)"
```

Nicer formatting:

```ini
commands_post =
    python -c "\
        import subprocess; \
        subprocess.run(\
            ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'freeze', '--all', '--exclude-editable'], \
            stdout=open('requirements.d/pytest.txt', 'w'), \
            text=True,\
        )\
    "
```

This solution uses the `stdout` parameter to hand over an output file, which should be fast.